# Doxygen: How to document PHP constants?

Tags: php, documentation, doxygen

How to document PHP constants:

```
define('SOME_CONSTANT', 'constant value');
```

with Doxygen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just include a documentation block above the constant `define()` function call or `const` keyword like this:

```
<?php

/**
 * Short Break Adventure Trip Sub Type Id
 */ 
const TRIP_SBA = 1;

/** 
 * Small Group Adventure Trip Sub Type Id
 */ 
define('TRIP_SGA', 2);

?>
```

Comment: The very same works for documenting class constants.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's what you are looking, but you can use the Define macro

```
   \def <name>
```

Something like:

```
  /*!
    \def SOME_CONSTANT
    some constant documentation
  */
```

Comment: No, @def is not what you want. That is referring to a C language construct I believe.