# Documenting PHP class constants in Doxygen

Tags: php, doxygen

What is the correct way to document PHP class constants with Doxygen ?

```
class Myclass {

    /**
     * What should I put here ?
     */
    const MY_CONST = 'value';
}
```

Based on [Doxygen tag list](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html) and some answers here on SO, I've tried the following :

- @var string MY_CONST + @brief description (like I would do for a regular member)
- @brief description (alone)
- @def MY_CONST description
- @const MY_CONST description (not in the tag list, but apparently this works in PHPDoc, so it was worth a try...)

None of these worked, the constant is not documented by Doxygen. What is the correct syntax ?

EDIT : [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7223832/doxygen-how-to-document-php-constants) marked as potential duplicate explains how to document global constants created with define(). As I said above, neither the @def syntax nor the brief description alone work for class constants created with "const" keyword.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7223832/doxygen-how-to-document-php-constants

Comment: Maybe this [filters](https://github.com/AbcAeffchen/doxygen-php-filters) can help you.

Comment: I tried, and unfortunately they don't. One of them does improve Doxygen's ability to parse the "var" tag on class members, but it will still not accept "var" for constants.

That's still an interesting idea though. I guess there is a lack of support for class constants in Doxygen, a custom filter is probably the best way to work around that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Doxygen how to document PHP constants](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7223832/doxygen-how-to-document-php-constants)

Comment: I am using Doxygen 1.8.6 and it just works for me. The constant shows up below `Public Attributes` for the class, and the long description below `Member Data Documentation` on the same page.